# Core Data error 'Misconfigured Enity: In the Compound Indexes attribute...is not a valid property' after adding and then removing indexes

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4.5

I was playing around with compound indexes for one of my entities. I added 2 (I simply clicked the 'add' button twice) and removed them right away (by clicking the remove button). Now when I build, I receive the error:

**Misconfigured Entity: In the Compound Indexes attribute for entity Entity, is not a valid property.**

I have already tried:

1. Deleting derived data
2. Cleaning project
3. Closing Xcode
4. Deleting app from simulator

Recreating the corresponding Entity classes and repeating the above

but the error persists. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

**EDIT**: I finally rolled things back to a previous version, but I would still love to know what went wrong.

Comment: delete app from device/simaulator

Comment: Yes, forget to mention that I did this too. Will edit above.

Comment: I wish I could mark a best answer, but I am not working on any Xcode projects right now.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to edit the .xcdatamodeld/.xcdatamodel/contents file (XML) directly with a text editor to remove the indexes tag on the effected entity.

This seemed to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 6, the way I resolved this was to select the "Project" > "Clean Build Folder..." (menu item changed from "Clean" when holding the "Option" key).

Then quit and relaunch Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, I think the @smw way is the good one ( cleaning can be necessary as well )
But today, 11 June 2015, as apple annouces iOS9 and new music streaming service - this stupid bug is still not fixed ( xCode 6.3 ).
More than 3 years…
Do they really use CoreData? :D

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Seems a bug of Xcode.

I had to revert the `<app>.xcdatamodeld/<app>.xcdatamodel/contents` file to the last-known-good state to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by cleaning, removing the build dir in the project dir and removing the corresponding DerivedData dir under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. Definitely looks like an Xcode bug.

I had previously had an index on an attribute that I had removed, but it seemed to keep the index around even though the UI in Xcode showed it was gone. The contents file under the data model also had it gone.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to avoid this by removing any compound indexes that reference a given attribute before you remove the attribute itself.

If any of your compound indexes are for a single attribute, consider using the 'indexed' property on the attribute as opposed to the compound index list – that way when you remove the attribute the index will be removed automatically.